# Angular call function inside fetch (ngOninit)

Tags: angular, fetch, function-call, uncaught-exception, ngoninit

I want to call a function inside a *fetch*, but for some reason I get the following error and can't find a solution.

```
 Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myFunction')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myFunction')
```

How I should call a function inside the fetch -> then ?
Minimalist reproduction at the link below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/kizI9pLOe8XZzKYz?preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your context is getting lost when you are declaring a function.

Use Arrow function to avoid that error as below:

```
fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/row-data.json').then( (response) => {
  return response.json();
}).then( (data) =>{
  this.myFunction(data);
})
```